# Move Files From One Location To Another And Exclude Subfolders

Tags: powershell

I want to move files from one location to another but not to move any files from subfolders in the directory I'm moving the files from.

I have the following code but this moves files in subfolders. Also, the extensions should only be .xml and .pdf.

This script moves all files from `$MoveThese` into the Destination, even the files in subfolders e.g. `C:\Test\Folder1\Subfolder`. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
$MoveThese = "C:\Test\Folder1", "C:\Test2\Folder2", "C:\Test3\Folder3"
$Destination = "C:\Test\Docs", "C:\Test2\Docs", "C:\Test3\Docs"

For($i=0; $i -lt $FailFolders.Length; $i++){
Get-ChildItem -Path $MoveThese[$i] -Recurse -Include "*.xml", "*.pdf" | Move-Item -Destination $Destination[$i] 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want files in subfolders, don't use `-Recurse`. As per [Get-ChildItem documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) this *"Gets the items in the specified locations **and in all child items** of the locations."*

---

Missed this part of the `-Include` statement:

> The -Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the
>   -Recurse parameter

Solution:

```
Get-ChildItem  $MoveThese[$i] -File |
    Where-Object {$_.Extension -in @(".xml",".pdf")} |
    Move-Item -Destination $Destination[$i]
```

Comment: When I remove -Recurse, this doesn't move any items in the $MoveThese location.

Comment: The `-Include` is no longer working - please see edit

Answer (score 0):

Include does not work without the `-Recurse` switch unfortunately unless the path uses a wildcard like in `C:\Windows*`

This might do it for you:

```
$MoveThese = "C:\Test\Folder1", "C:\Test2\Folder2", "C:\Test3\Folder3"
$Destination = "C:\Test\Docs", "C:\Test2\Docs", "C:\Test3\Docs"

For($i=0; $i -lt $MoveThese.Length; $i++){
  Get-ChildItem  $MoveThese[$i] -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*.xml" -or $_.Name -like "*.pdf" | 
    Move-Item -Destination $Destination[$i] -Force
}
```